# Why do I need to do floating point arithmetic with Math.floor

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Why does:
`Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(128.766*1000));`

Yield a different result to:

`Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor((decimal)128.766*1000));`

Surely the correct answer is 128766 whether working with an int or a decimal. (I am familiar with casting to a decimal for division for example.)

I'm using .NET 4.5 C#

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx . Read this. One Маth.Floor return decimal other double, that's why.

Comment: Run this for a hint of what is going on: [`Console.WriteLine((128.766*100).ToString("e20"))`](https://ideone.com/s01m87)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line uses floating point maths, which is inaccurate. `128.766*1000` might evaluate to `128765.99999999999` or something similar.

`Math.Floor` rounds this down to become `128765`.

However, in the second line, you converted the result to `decimal` first, before `Math.Floor`. Converting to decimal removes this inaccuracy, since `decimal` is 128-bit and has a smaller range. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) for more info. When you convert `128765.9999999999` to a `decimal`, it got turned into `128766`.

Comment: `decimal` is itself a floating point type and in general certainly does have the same inaccuracy problem as all floating point types. It's just that the OP's values can be represented exactly.